# Jest: Specific selector

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

The following is part of my render function in React.

```
//some code
<div className='icon-container'>
  <Icon name='close' />
</div>
```

While testing this, I have mounted my component. I would like to specifically select the `Icon` component which is within my `icon-container` `div`.
How do I do that?

**Note:** There could be multiple `Icons` rendered while mounting in jest. Hence I require specificity. Also, I cannot use shallow since I would like to test the HOC functionality wrapped over the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `.find` method of enzyme as shown below code

```
componentWrapper.find(".icon-container [name='close']")
```

or

```
componentWrapper.find(".icon-container <use-icon-class-name-or-id>")
```

Read more about the EnzymeSelector [here](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html)

Answer (score -1):

Can you explain a title more about what you want to do with that icon, i.e change size, apply animation or what ? I think you don't have to directly inject the Icon component.

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer.